# Errors reported during upload and display of wrong path names

Tags: php, html

I have a form that uploads two images and saves the path to them in DB.

```
if (isset($_POST['add_artimage'])) {
    if ($_FILES["front"]) {
        upload_file("front");
    }
    if ($_FILES["back"]) {
        upload_file("back");
    }
    $front = upload_file($front);
    $back = upload_file($back);
    echo "image_front is $front <br> image_back is $back";
}

function upload_file($name) {
    $folder = "prod-images/";
    $folder2 = "users/";
    $open_type_upload = ".jpg";
    
    $file_name = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES[$name]['type'];
    $rand_file_name = rand(1000000000, 9999999999999);
    
    $newfile_name = $rand_file_name.$file_name;
    $open_types = array(
        "image/jpg",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/png",
        "image/gif");
    $upload = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $folder.$rand_file_name.$open_type_upload);
    echo "ok";
    $image = "$folder2$folder$rand_file_name$open_type_upload";
    return $image;
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<td>image_front:</td>
<td><input name='front' type='file' id='ufile'  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>image_back:</td>
<td><input name='back' type='file' id='ufile'  /></td>
```

When I try to upload, it uploads the files to the dir, but also reports some errors like the following:

> Notice: Undefined variable: front
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: back
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: index

When `echo`ing the path to `image_front` and `image_back`, it `echo`s different names from their real ones in the uploaded dir.

Comment: Where have you defined those `variable`s?

Comment: I have improved the formatting of the first code block, corrected the formatting for the error messages (message should not be formatted as code blocks) and reworded the title to better explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$front` and `$back` are not defined, you should consider the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_artimage'])) {

    $front = $back = 'not uploaded';

    if ($_FILES["front"])
        $front = upload_file("front");

    if ($_FILES["back"])
        $back = upload_file("back");

    echo "image_front is $front <br> image_back is $back";
}
```